# Set environment variables from Delphi (Win32)

Tags: delphi, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a system wide environment variable from within my delphi application. The Documentation says to add a registry key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment and then broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message. Anyone know how to Broadcast this message?

PS. I'm trying to do this in a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a topic in the Embarcadero Developer Network covering this issue and providing sample code for sending the message. The author uses [**SendMessageTimeout**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952.aspx) as recommended in the MSDN doc for [**WM_SETTINGCHANGE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497.aspx):

**http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28254**

Comment: I used the code from the article linked. I found that setting the Path in environment using Reg.WriteString IS WRONG, it should use Reg.WriteExpandString

Answer (score 5):

Call [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx). Use `HWnd_Broadcast` as the target window.

A better option may be [`SendNotifyMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644953.aspx), which doesn't wait for all the recipients to return.