# Using SendNotifyMessage in an installer

Tags: delphi, winapi, inno-setup

In an Inno install script, I am setting an environment variable by adding an entry to:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment.
```

I want my users to be able to run the newly installed app without having to reboot (which would normally be necessary for the above change to be seen in the environment.)

I plan to have the installer use a dll to call *SendMessageTimeOut*, as discussed here: [Set environment variables from Delphi (Win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009180/set-environment-variables-from-delphi-win32).

Delphi XE2 reports this API is deprecated.

And the above StackOverflow thread suggests using *SendNotifyMessage* to avoid long waits. I don't know how to construct that call.

Can anyone show me the syntax? Is it deprecated too?

Any suggestions on a better approach?

Tom

Comment: I don't see any reason for `SendMessageTimeOut` to be deprecated. Are you sure?

Comment: *"Invalid API definition, use other overload"*, use the other overload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [ChangesEnvironment](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_changesenvironment) directive.  From the docs:

> When set to yes, at the end of the installation Setup will notify
>   other running applications (notably Windows Explorer) that they should
>   reload their environment variables from the registry.

Comment: Worked great!

This is a case of RTFM if I ever saw one!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Neither function is deprecated. Delphi says `SendMessageTimeout` is deprecated because *that declaration* is deprecated. The API function itself is fine. Since you'd be calling it from something that isn't Delphi, whatever Delphi says about *its* declaration is irrelevant to you.

Since you don't actually care about the return value of the message, `SendNotifyMessage` is the superior choice. It won't wait at all for a response, whereas `SendMessageTimeout` will wait a little while to get a response, which you're just going to ignore anyway.

But as Mirtheil's answer points out, the installer environment you're using already provides a way of notifying other programs that the environment changed, so you should use that instead of trying to do it manually.